# The most recent request was denied because it contained an invalid security token. Please refresh the page and try again. in ArkEditor

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I get the error "The most recent request was denied because it contained an invalid security token. Please refresh the page and try again." in Ark Editor when i try to upload a image. What can i do to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem i just modified "php.ini" "upload..." and "post..." because i use large images. The real trick was to restart apache with "/etc/init.d/apache2 restart" instead of "service apache2 restart". Thanks a lot for your answer i appreciate:)!

Answer (score 0):

You can clean your browser cache, cookies and also clean your joomla cache. This happens sometimes due to caching or cookie issues.